# Widest angular of binocular vision

Tags: homework, eyes

> Which out of eagle, rat, duck or owl has the widest angle of binocular vision?

I am pretty sure it's not rat and duck but I am confused between owl and eagle. Can anybody help me figure out which one would have the widest angle of binocular vision?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. Did you do any research yourself on binocular vision?

Comment: @Ebbinghaus I did but couldn't really find anything. This is not a homework question I found it in a question paper and wasn't able to find the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at some pictures of eagle and owl and observe their beaks. It will help you in concluding which might have the widest binocular vision angle.